# Buck Rogers and Starbuck

Tags: battlestar-galactica, character-development, battlestar-galactica-1978, buck-rogers

Is there any (out of universe) connection between the in many ways similar characters Buck Rogers (1978) and Starbuck (Battlestar Galactica, same year)? E.g. same writers who just liked the name, a character developed for one franchise instead being used or reused in another, a reference to a real-world person named Buck famous in the late 1970s?

Comment: As for Starbuck I always assumed that was a hommage to Moby Dick. And Buck Rogers dates back to the 1920s, so this has not relation to anything in the 70s (although a "buck" is a male gerbil which might serve as an apt description for Gil Gerad).

Comment: Specifically, in Moby Dick Starbuck was the Chief (First) Mate on the Pequod. He is torn between opposition  to Ahab's quest for vengeance and his sense of duty to his captain.

Comment: The connection between the series of course is that both were written/produced by [Glen A Larson](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glen_A._Larson), which explains the very similar spacecraft but not necessarily the names.

Comment: This question would have been so much more interesting if it involved Starbucks and/or Templeton Peck.

Comment: A dog named Buck was the main character of Jack London's *The Call of the Wild*  Buck Turgidson was George C. Scott's character in *Dr. Strangelove*.  Buck Owens was a country singer. Bucky Bug is a Disney character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character "Buck Rogers" is rather much older than 1978. The television program is an adaptation of a character from the 1928 story [*Armageddon 2419 A.D.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armageddon_2419_A.D.), and more directly, of the ensuing comic strip *Buck Rogers in the 25th Century A.D.*, starting in 1929.

The show moves the story a bit into modern times (most prior adaptations had Rogers get caught in a mine and rendered unconscious by some unknown gas), but the general idea is the same. William Rogers is a from the 20th Century, usually former or current military, and somehow gets stuck in a state of suspended animation for about 500 years. He then awakens and quickly gets himself involved in the political or military events of the future.

The nickname "Buck" was apparently a rather popular one at the turn of the century, judging by the very long [list of people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_(nickname)) with that nickname on Wikipedia. The list includes, among other things, a former President.

---

The character of Starbuck, in *Battlestar Galactica*, was named after the first mate of the *Pequod* in *Moby Dick*, which was published in 1851.

Comment: Starbuck was also a New England (North-East U.S.) family name often connected with the sailing industry. There's still a Starbuck Atoll somewhere in the Pacific.

Comment: **William** Rogers? The hero of the 1928 magazine story was named **Anthony** Rogers. Was his name changed to William in one of the adaptations?